# I need to use RegEx to find a speciffic word in HTML page?

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to extract a specific word (that might change) which comes after a permanent expression. I want to extract the name `Taldor` in this code:

```
<h4 class="t-16 t-black t-normal">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Company Name</span>
    <span class="pv-entity__secondary-title">Taldor</span>
</h4>
```

For now I able to find `<h4 class="t-16 t-black t-normal">` using this regex:

```
(?<=<h4 class="t-16 t-black t-normal">).*
```

Will be glad for any kind of advice.

Comment: I wouldn't use RegEx to parse HTML. It's strongly advised to not do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use an HTML parsing library like [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) in Java or [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) in Python to parse HTML instead of using regex for [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Following is the kind of code that does the job for you,

```
String s = "<h4 class=\"t-16 t-black t-normal\">\r\n" + 
        "    <span class=\"visually-hidden\">Company Name</span>\r\n" + 
        "    <span class=\"pv-entity__secondary-title\">Taldor</span>\r\n" + 
        "  </h4>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
for (Element element : doc.getElementsByClass("pv-entity__secondary-title")) {
    System.out.println(element.text());
    break;
}
```

Prints,

```
Taldor
```

In worst case, if you are doing some quick and dirty work, you can do this temporary solution using regex but it is surely not recommended thing to do.

```
<span class="pv-entity__secondary-title">(.*?)<\/span>
```

Use this regex and capture your data from group1.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h6Ywcr/1)**